# Azure DevOps Projects List GET not returning a project

Tags: azure-devops

When running the Azure DevOps Projects List GET, one particular Project is excluded from the results. I cannot find any different settings. I am the admin of it. I can add new projects, and there were projects I created before it, that all show up in the results. It's the API call as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I cannot find explanation of why a project is excluded from the results aside from Project State, which I have troubleshot already.

I've already tried running the GET API in the browser and I do not return the missing project. I have tried creating another project in the same manner and it appears in what is returned. I have added an argument for Project State = All, and that does not improve the outcome.

Under what circumstances is a project excluded from these results as a standard (undocumented) constraint?

---

edit: I am a project admin, and I have access to the default project team. I have tried recycling things in the background by changing the Project Name back and forth, and having myself removed as Admin and added back in, with no change in the API response.

---

edit: It seems like the more important question is how to force Azure DevOps to cycle the 'lastUpdateDate', when it's currently set to a non-date.

Comment: Can you view this missing project from page UI? It seems that if you can view this project from page, you will also get these projects list in the api result.

Comment: Yes, I can view this project from the page UI in Azure DevOps. But it is not returned by the API. I noticed this when trying to run an integration to another online service, and with their help, validated this down to the API itself.

Comment: What's the error message do you get while you execute the 'Get' command? Did you try with accessing the content of this missing project?

Comment: There is no error on API response. It returns all other Projects but this one. And it doesn't seem to have any setting different, and my access seems to be identical in DevOps, compared to Projects that are being returned. That's why it baffles me. What do you mean with "Did you try with accessing the content of this missing project?"

Comment: What about the API response code while you execute GET this missing project(Not List)? For>>access the content of this missing project, I mean could you access such as repos, pipelines or any other with API?

Comment: To run those other API calls I believe I need the Project ID...I am not clear how to get it other than the API call that isn't returning it. Is there a way to see the Project ID string in DevOps?

Comment: No, don’t need projectid. Just project name is ok. I am confusing about what the response message and state code you received while you execute GET the missing project. Sometimes we can know exactly info from these response code.

Comment: Projects GET returns a response with the expected details, when using the Project Name instead of ID. Status Code 200. State is "wellFormed". Still nothing from Project List. However, lastUpdateTime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", and Revision: 1901. That seems off.

Comment: Could you update your question with the List api you used and response info?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that the result set for the call is 100 entries. So you either need to use the `continuationToken` to get the next 100 entries, and so on. Otherwise, you can also use the `$top` query parameter:

```
https://-collection_url-/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0&$top=200
```